# How to apply itertools.product to elements of a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have a list of arrays and I would like to get the cartesian product of the elements in the arrays.

I will use an example to make this more concrete...

itertools.product seems to do the trick but I am stuck in a little detail.

```
arrays = [(-1,+1), (-2,+2), (-3,+3)];
```

If I do

```
cp = list(itertools.product(arrays));
```

I get

```
cp = cp0 = [((-1, 1),), ((-2, 2),), ((-3, 3),)]
```

But what I want to get is

```
cp1 = [(-1,-2,-3), (-1,-2,+3), (-1,+2,-3), (-1,+2,+3), ..., (+1,+2,-3), (+1,+2,+3)].
```

I have tried a few different things:

```
cp = list(itertools.product(itertools.islice(arrays, len(arrays))));
cp = list(itertools.product(iter(arrays, len(arrays))));
```

They all gave me *cp0* instead of *cp1*.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have the answers below, but this has some good use cases for  the itertools product function: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/itertools-product

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
>>> list(itertools.product(*arrays))
[(-1, -2, -3), (-1, -2, 3), (-1, 2, -3), (-1, 2, 3), (1, -2, -3), (1, -2, 3), (1, 2, -3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

This will feed all the pairs as separate arguments to `product`, which will then give you the cartesian product of them.

The reason your version isn't working is that you are giving `product` only one argument. Asking for a cartesian product of one list is a trivial case, and returns a list containing only one element (the list given as argument).

Answer (score 40):

```
>>> arrays = [(-1,+1), (-2,+2), (-3,+3)]
>>> list(itertools.product(*arrays))
[(-1, -2, -3), (-1, -2, 3), (-1, 2, -3), (-1, 2, 3), (1, -2, -3), (1, -2, 3), (1, 2, -3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: does having an asterix prefix an array have special meaning in python or is this just something specific to itertools.product?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5239856/395857 and [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in three rurch using itertools.product

```
lst=[]
arrays = [(-1,+1), (-2,+2), (-3,+3)]  

import itertools 

for i in itertools.product(*arrays):
         lst.append(i)



print(lst)
```

[image]