# Python: How to transform a 'flat' sequence into a sequence of tuples?

Tags: python, list, forms, tuples

I needed to make a list of 2-tuples out of a one-dimensional list of coordinates, for example 
`[1, 2, 1, 5]`
needed to become `[(1, 2), (1, 5)]`.  As it happens I've already found the fastest, most general way to do this, at [Activestate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303060-group-a-list-into-sequential-n-tuples/), but the code listed there is opaque to a relative Python newbie:

```
def group3(lst, n):
    return itertools.izip(*[itertools.islice(lst, i, None, n) for i in range(n)])
```

Can anyone explain what this code is doing in English?  What is the asterisk doing in this context??  Thank you.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python/5239873#5239873) to another question about the asterisk

Comment: I can explain it in Python.  `itertools` is there for efficiency.  Replace it with the respective built-in functions, and it becomes `return zip(*[lst[i::n] for i in range(n)])` which is hopefully easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.islice) function can produce a slice from any iterable. The statement:

```
itertools.islice(lst, 0, None, 2)
```

In simplified terms means "return an iterator which, when evaluated, will return every other element in lst starting with the element at 0". The `0` arg is the starting point and `2` is the step value (how many to skip to get the next value)

It would be better to use a 6-element list to illustrate, since looking at `[(1, 2), (1, 5)]` it may be unclear which function produces the inner tuples (they are not produced until the final izip).

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(itertools.islice(lst, 0, None, 2))
[1, 3, 5]
>>> list(itertools.islice(lst, 0, None, 2))
[2, 4, 6]
```

Be careful using this with a generator; the first call will traverse the whole sequence, draining the generator:

```
>>> def foo():
...     for i in range(6):
...         yield i + 1
>>>
>>> gen = foo()
>>> list(itertools.islice(gen, 0, None, 2)
[1, 3, 5]
>>> list(itertools.islice(gen, 1, None, 2)
[]
```

Your function needs to produce 2 sequences, odds and evens. This is where the list comprehension comes in:

```
>>> [itertools.islice(lst, i, None, 2) for i in range(2)]
[<itertools.islice object at 0x7f958a79eaf8>, <itertools.islice object at 0x7f958a79eaa0>]
```

Now you have 2 islice objects ready to be interleaved. To do this we could use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip), but  [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.izip) is more efficient because it returns an iterator:

```
>>> list(zip([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> tmp = itertools.izip(*[itertools.islice(lst, i, None, 2) for i in range(2)])
>>> tmp
<itertools.izip object at 0x7f958a7b6cf8>
>>> list(tmp)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Hope that helps clarify the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate version for 2-tuples (not as general as the active state recipe):

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> [ (x.pop(0), x.pop(0)) for item in range(len(x)/2) ]
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

This forms a list of two-tuples by popping the first two numbers off the list until there are no more pairs left.