# Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples

Tags: python, list, split, tuples

I have a list that looks like this:

```
my_list = [('1','a'),('2','b'),('3','c'),('4','d')]
```

I want to separate the list in 2 lists.

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4']
list2 = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I can do it for example with:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
for i in list:
   list1.append(i[0])
   list2.append(i[1])
```

But I want to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Please do not use built-in type names for variables.  Don't call it `list`.  Once you've created a variable `list`, you start to have weird things happen because the built-in function `list()` is now hidden by your variable.

Comment: That's a tuple, not a list. It's important to keep them straight in Python, even though they can be used similarly.

Answer (score 538, accepted):

```
>>> source_list = [('1','a'),('2','b'),('3','c'),('4','d')]
>>> list1, list2 = zip(*source_list)
>>> list1
('1', '2', '3', '4')
>>> list2
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

**Edit:** Note that `zip(*iterable)` is its own inverse:

```
>>> list(source_list) == zip(*zip(*source_list))
True
```

When unpacking into two lists, this becomes:

```
>>> list1, list2 = zip(*source_list)
>>> list(source_list) == zip(list1, list2)
True
```

Addition suggested by rocksportrocker.

Comment: To the OP, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python is helpful if you don't know about the "splat" operator.

Comment: I want to point out that the results of `zip(*list_of_pairs)` is not a pair of `list` but `tuple`. The difference can be important in some cases (e.g. append to it). So the `list1` and `list2` in the example should really be `tuple1` and `tuple2`.

Comment: @Causality Definitely true. I used the same names used in the question, where they are also `tuple`s. The mistake was pointed out in a comment on the question back when this was originally posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples/7558990?noredirect=1#comment9163175_7558908

Comment: This is all fine and dandy until you get a `source_list` that has zero length. Then you will get an error instead of 2 empty lists like you would expect.

Answer (score 40):

```
list1 = (x[0] for x in source_list)
list2 = (x[1] for x in source_list)
```

Comment: If you need actual `list`s you can index, you should use square brackets `[]` instead of parenthesis to make them list comprehensions instead of generator expressions.

Comment: -1, the solution with zip() is more pythonic and doesn't have two for loops

Comment: @naeg, this is a perfectly correct, pythonic expression. You could even argue for the less trained programmer this is a better solution than to use the quite foggy `zip(*...)` syntax.

Comment: @KillianDS: Well, I don't consider the zip() function nor the unpacking of arguments as complex or foggy? Since the zip-answer has more upvotes, I guess others think the same.

Comment: It depends on the length of the tuples in the original list. If it is unknown or beyond 2, zip(* ) is better, otherwise, the solution here is nice too.

Comment: For anyone wondering, zip is faster: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufedP.png

Comment: @sachinruk zip is NOT faster. A loop with an append is not equivalent to a comprehension expression. The list comprehension version is faster. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJVIX.png