# LINQ: List of tuples to tuple of lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Tuple<A,B>>` and would like to know if there is a way in LINQ to return `Tuple<List<A>,List<B>>`

This is similar to the following Python question: [Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx):

```
Tuple<List<A>, List<B>> Unpack<A, B>(List<Tuple<A, B>> list)
{
    return list.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(new List<A>(list.Count), new List<B>(list.Count)),
                          (unpacked, tuple) =>
                          {
                              unpacked.Item1.Add(tuple.Item1);
                              unpacked.Item2.Add(tuple.Item2);
                              return unpacked;
                          });
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It's not possible with a single LINQ call, however you can do it quite easily with code:

```
Tuple<List<A>, List<B>> Unpack<A, B>(List<Tuple<A, B>> list)
{
  var listA = new List<A>(list.Count);
  var listB = new List<B>(list.Count);
  foreach (var t in list)
  {
    listA.Add(t.Item1);
    listB.Add(t.Item2);
  }

  return Tuple.Create(listA, listB);
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most simple way of doing it without enumerating over the list twice.

Comment: Why do you initialize the capacity of the two lists? Is there a performance benefit?

Comment: @Aducci Yes, you aren't resizing the internal buffer continually.

Comment: @Aducci A list has an internal buffer that can hold up to N elements. When you add more elements and the buffer becomes to small, then a new buffer will be created, all elements copied over and the new buffer is used - this is a slow process. When you know the amount of elements you can tell the List "Hey, I want you to initially allocate enough memory to hold N elements", thus there won't be any new allocation necessary.

Comment: It might be even more efficient to use [`List.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) after you've set the capacity instead of the `foreach`, for example: `listA.AddRange(list.Select(t => t.Item1));`

Comment: It can be written slightly more tersely but in essence is exactly the same: `var unpacked = new Tuple<List<int>, List<string>>(new List<int>(pairs.Count), new List<string>(pairs.Count));

            pairs.ForEach(pair => 
                {
                    unpacked.Item1.Add(pair.Item1);
                    unpacked.Item2.Add(pair.Item2);
                });`

Comment: @TimSchmelter That way you'd have to enumerate the list twice again, which I wanted to prevent.

Comment: @Servy martine1921- Interesting, it is a nice little optimization. thank you.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth That is no more concise than the code posted here.  If you remove the whitespace from this code it is just as compact.

Comment: @Martin1921 It's actually not really much of an enumeration.  Enumerating a list twice is almost the same as enumerating a list twice and doing half as much work each time.  You have a little extra overhead of manipulating the loop variables twice, but that's pretty small.  It's the general reason why LINQ isn't all that efficient.  Having lots of loops that don't do a lot is only a tad less efficient than one loop that does it all.

Comment: @Servy I beg to differ, mine chops out one line :-) but I actually meant terse in terms of local variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
Tuple<List<A>, List<B>> Unpack<A, B>(List<Tuple<A, B>> list) {
            return Tuple.Create(list.Select(e => e.Item1).ToList(),list.Select(e => e.Item2).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public Tuple<List<int>,List<int>> Convert(List<Tuple<int, int>> BaseList)
{
    return new Tuple<List<int>,List<int>>((from tuple in BaseList
                                                        select tuple.Item1).ToList(),
                                                        (from tuple in BaseList
                                                        select tuple.Item2).ToList());
}
```

I considered it is a list of integer

Comment: then he can just replace int with object

Comment: No, he shouldn't.  The method should be generic, so that it's still strongly typed but can use any arbitrary type.