# Plotting a list of (x, y) coordinates

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot, coordinates

I have a list of pairs `(a, b)` that I would like to plot with `matplotlib` in python as actual x-y coordinates. Currently, it is making two plots, where the index of the list gives the x-coordinate, and the first plot's y values are the `a`s in the pairs and the second plot's y values are the `b`s in the pairs.

To clarify, my data looks like this: `li = [(a,b), (c,d), ... , (t, u)]` and I want to do a one-liner that just calls `plt.plot()`.
If I didn't require a one-liner I could trivially do:

```py
xs = [x[0] for x in li]
ys = [x[1] for x in li]
plt.plot(xs, ys)
```

How can I get matplotlib to plot these pairs as x-y coordinates?

---

### Sample data

```py
# sample data
li = list(zip(range(1, 14), range(14, 27)))

li → [(1, 14), (2, 15), (3, 16), (4, 17), (5, 18), (6, 19), (7, 20), (8, 21), (9, 22), (10, 23), (11, 24), (12, 25), (13, 26)]
```

### Incorrect Plot

```py
plt.plot(li)
plt.title('Incorrect Plot:\nEach index of the tuple plotted as separate lines')
```

[image]

### Desired Plot

This produces the correct plot, but to many lines of code are used to unpack `li`. I need to unpack and plot with a single line of code, not multiple list-comprehensions.

```py
xs = [x[0] for x in li]
ys = [x[1] for x in li]
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.title('Correct Plot:\nBut uses to many lines to unpack li')
```

[image]

Comment: Essentially, this is a question about how to unpack a list of tuples, which is addressed with [Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7558990/7758804). However, that answer doesn't show how to unpack the `zip` object into the plot API.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Given `li` in the question:

```
li = list(zip(range(1, 14), range(14, 27)))
```

To unpack the data from pairs into lists use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
x, y = zip(*li)

x → (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
y → (14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26)
```

The one-liner uses the [unpacking operator (*)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/), to unpack the list of tuples for `zip`, and unpacks the `zip` object into the plot API.

```
plt.scatter(*zip(*li))
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(*zip(*li))
```

[image]

Answer (score 71):

If you have a numpy array you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 6],
])
x, y = data.T
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So there is no way to have a `np.array` of `data=np.array([[x1,y1],[x2,y2],etc.])` and using `plt.plot(data)`.  I'll always have to give two arrays instead of arrays of arrays?

Comment: @MaxCoplan, that's right, but you could use `plt.plot(*data.T)` which does the same as the above but skips the intermediate step.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to plot a single line connecting all the points in the list

```
plt.plot(li[:])

plt.show()
```

This will plot a line connecting all the pairs in the list as points on a Cartesian plane from the starting of the list to the end.
I hope that this is what you wanted.

Comment: He didn't want to plot a single line, he wanted to plot with a "one-liner" (a single line of code). The answer he was looking for (and got 3 years ago) was to use `scatter()`.

Comment: @Gathide: Yes, it deserves a downvote, since it doesn't work at all, and doesn't fit the description. `plt.plot(li)` is just like `plt.plot(li[:])`. It simply plots 2 lines, using the pairs as `(y1, y2)` and not as `(x1, y1)`.

Comment: The comment by @Dartmouth is only half correct. The OP wants to generate one plot line, with a one-liner. The OP states _**If I didn't require a one-liner I could trivially do**_, followed by the code to produce a single line. This answer does not solve the question. It produces the same unwanted double line plot the OP already has.