# how to sum the elements generated using loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

experts i want to get the sum of the elements generated by for loop(x) in python.I wrote a programme for that but i am not getting the sum of x values.please help.

```
import numpy as np

f=np.arange(1,2,1)

for i in f:
    #print(i)
    for m in np.arange(1,6,1):
        x=((4.6)*(m*2)*(5)**2)*(i)/62
        print(x)
        #print(np.sum(x))
```

Comment: It looks like you were printing out intermediate values as you were writing this code to get a better sense of what was happening. Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and initialize a variable outside the loop and add x to that variable.

```
import numpy as np

f=np.arange(1,5,1)

for i in f:
    sum = 0
    for m in np.arange(1,6,1):
        x=((4.6)*(m*2)*(5)**2)*(i)/62
        sum += x
    print(i, sum)
```

Output:

```
1 55.64516129032258
2 111.29032258064515
3 166.93548387096774
4 222.5806451612903
```

Comment: btw Don't use `sum` as a variable name. It is a built-in.

Comment: sum is not a keyword in python. Following code will return False, let me know if I am missing something ####
import keyword
print('sum' in keyword.kwlist)

Comment: @glkshu Please tell what is your excepted output in both cases np.arange(1,2,1) and np.arange(1,5,1)

Comment: sum is not a keyword in python. It is a built-in, just like enumerate, list or zip.

Comment: Ok. got your point. Updated code. Please check if this works

Comment: @glkshu This may help [Plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519203/plotting-a-list-of-x-y-coordinates-in-python-matplotlib) 
But for this, you will have to add all `sum` in a list.

Answer (score 2):

As I suppose, you want to compute the sum of **all** generated values.

The first, "classic" and not very efficient method is to
create a list, append each generaed element to this list
and then compute the sum of this list:

```
f = np.arange(1,2)
tbl = []
for i in f:
    for m in np.arange(1,6):
        x = ((4.6)*(m*2)*(5)**2)*(i)/62
        print(f'{i}, {m}: {x:.4f}')
        tbl.append(x)
print(sum(tbl))
```

The result is:

```
1, 1: 3.7097
1, 2: 7.4194
1, 3: 11.1290
1, 4: 14.8387
1, 5: 18.5484
55.64516129032258
```

But a more efficient and *numpythonic* option is to use *np.fromfunction*
method to generate the whole *Numpy* array in one go and then compute its
sum:

```
arr = np.fromfunction(lambda i, m: 4.6 * m * 2 * 5 ** 2 * i / 62, (2, 6))
print(arr)
print(arr.sum())
```

Note that I removed unncessary parentheses from your code.

Your function can actually be yet more simplified to:

```
lambda i, m: i * m * 9.2 * 5 ** 2 / 62
```

This time the result is:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          3.70967742  7.41935484 11.12903226 14.83870968 18.5483871 ]]
55.64516129032258
```

## Edit

From one of other answers I see that you may be interested in a
sequence of **cumulative** sums of your values.

After you generate *arr*, you can generate such a sequence with:

```
np.cumsum(arr[1:,1:])
```

even for more than one rows (values of *i*). Test it e.g. for shape
of `(3, 6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just append your x to a list and use sum().

```py
import numpy as np



f=np.arange(1,2,1)

for i in f:
    items = []
    for m in np.arange(1,6,1):
        x=((4.6)*(m*2)*(5)**2)*(i)/62
        items.append(x)
    print(sum(items))
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what answers you are looking for. What are the expected values for your two scenarios?

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t know what answers you are looking for. Perhaps you could update your question with some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Ok, now printing multiple sums.