# Join unique values into new data frame (python, pandas)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have two dataFrames, from where I extract the unique values of a column into a and b

```
a = df1.col1.unique()
b = df2.col2.unique()
```

now a and b are something like this

```
['a','b','c','d'] #a
[1,2,3] #b
```

they are now type numpy.ndarray

I want to join them to have a DataFrame like this

```
   col1  col2
0    a     1
1    a     2
3    a     3
4    b     1
5    b     2
6    b     3
7    c     1
   . . .
```

Is there a way to do it not using a loop?

Comment: Is a list comprehension acceptable?

Comment: I need it to be DataFrame

Comment: @RoseAlejandra - No, I'm asking if a list comprehension is acceptable in order to create the DataFrame. You say without a 'for loop', which list comprehensions use implicitly, but not explicitly.

Comment: I don't mind the use of them implicitly @AkshatMahajan

Comment: @RosaAlejandra, please pay attention at B. M.'s solution - it's __much__ faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

B. M.'s solution utilizing numpy is much faster - i would recommend to use his approach:

```
In [88]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.repeat(aa,bb.size),'col2':np.tile(bb,aa.size)})
10 loops, best of 3: 25.4 ms per loop

In [89]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(list(product(aa,bb)), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.28 s per loop

In [90]: aa.size
Out[90]: 1000

In [91]: bb.size
Out[91]: 1000
```

try [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [56]: a
Out[56]:
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      dtype='<U1')

In [57]: b
Out[57]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [63]: pd.DataFrame(list(product(a,b)), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
Out[63]:
   col1  col2
0     a     1
1     a     2
2     a     3
3     b     1
4     b     2
5     b     3
6     c     1
7     c     2
8     c     3
9     d     1
10    d     2
11    d     3
```

Comment: Since `itertools.product(a,b)` returns an iterator consisting of tuples, I suspect the additional list comprehension to `[[x[0],x[1]]` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

with numpy tools :

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.repeat(a,b.size),'col2':np.tile(b,a.size)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this task without using at least one for loop. The best you can do is *hide* the for loop or make use of implicit `yield` calls to make a memory-efficient generator.

`itertools` exports efficient functions for this task that use `yield` implicitly to return generators:

```
from itertools import product

products = product(['a','b','c','d'], [1,2,3])

col1_items, col2_items = zip(*products)

result = pandas.DataFrame({'col1':col1_items, 'col2': col2_items})
```

`itertools.product` creates a [Cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of two iterables. The `zip(*products)` simply unpacks the resulting list of tuples into two separate tuples, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas merge and it will be faster than itertools or a loop:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'key': 1})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'b': b, 'key': 1})
result = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='outer')
```

result:

```
    a  key  b
0   a    1  1
1   a    1  2
2   a    1  3
3   b    1  1
4   b    1  2
5   b    1  3
6   c    1  1
7   c    1  2
8   c    1  3
9   d    1  1
10  d    1  2
11  d    1  3
```

then if need be you can always do

```
del result['key']
```