# Getting a list of POS tags only from the tuples of (word,pos_tag)

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I have a list of list of sentences, tokenized by words and then pos tagged so the results is obviously is a list with elements:

```
[(w1,pos_tag1)(w2,pos_tag2)]
[(w3,pos_tag3),(w4,pos_tag4),(w5,pos_tag5)]
[(w6,pos_tag6),(w7,pos_tag7)]
```

I need to get a list of pos_tags only in the same order they happen in all sentences.What I tried was a iteration over the list

tags = [x[1] for x in element in list]

but this does not work.How can I have all tags in these lists?

thanks

Comment: Without seeing exactly what `tagged_words` is,  no one can tell... your code seems fine for what you are trying to do.

Comment: let me ask my question another way.I am stuck here: I have a list of lists.each list in the list is one sentence in the form of elements that are (word, pos_tag). so something like:

[[(w1,pos1),(w2,pos2),(w3,pos3)]
[(w4,pos4),(w5,pos5),(w6,pos6),...]
[...]]

and it goes on.So I want all pos tags in the order they happen in these sentences.

Comment: @roganjosh of course.I did

Comment: `for i element` is not valid Python code, could you change that?

Comment: Assuming that your example, _nested_ list is called `lst` then you could do `positions = [item[1] for sublist in lst for item in sublist]` but the output doesn't seem particularly useful so I'm not sure it's giving you the thing you need.

Answer (score 5):

You can unpack list of tuples using the `zip(*list)` idiom, see [Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples)

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> tagged_sent = pos_tag('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split()) 
>>> tagged_sent
[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'VBZ'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('lazy', 'JJ'), ('dog', 'NN')]
>>> words, tags = zip(*tagged_sent)
>>> tags
('DT', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NN', 'VBZ', 'IN', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN')
```

Comment: great.This works.But the problem is that when I do this, I only receive the tags for the last sentence in the list of sentences.Why is that so?

Comment: I use a function to tokenize words and pos tagging the sentences. So I try to use the tagged sentences out of function using funtion.tagged_senteces. When I print this out of function, I only receive the last item on the tagged sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of lists of word-tag pairs:

```
tagged_sentences = [[(w1, t1), (w2, t2), ...], [(w5, t5), ...],...]
```

you can do the following to get a list of lists of tags:

```
> tags = [[tag for word, tag in sent] for sent in tagged_sentences]
# tags = [[x[1] for x in sent] for sent in tagged_sentences]
[[t1, t2, ...], [t5, ...], ...]
```

If you want to flatten the list, i.e. get a flat list of all the tags from all sentences:

```
> tags = [tag for sent in tagged_sentences for word, tag in sent]
# tags = [x[1] for sent in tagged_sentences for x in sent]
[t1, t2, ..., t5, ...]
```

Comment: I'm curious; your bottom example includes a hashed line of code that is how I approached it in the comments. Is there any particular reason you might favour the unhashed version above it?

Comment: Interestingly, it runs faster according to `timeit`. 452ns vs 531ns. Is this due to the indexing?

Comment: @roganjosh No fundamental reason. Depending on the context, I think it can be more readable when everything involved gets a semantically meaningful name. In some contexts, I'd prefer it because it fails if `x` does not have exactly 2 elements. It is also more flexible, because `x` must support indexing in "your" version, while "my" version can deal with an iterator...

Comment: I get the following erro running the first line of both solutions:
    tags = [tag for sent in process_content.tagged for word, tag in sent]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Alma That should mean that your input list (`tagged_sentences`) does not have the form I describe in the solution.