# How to extract and plot the keys of a defaultdict based on the values

Tags: python, matplotlib, defaultdict

I am using defalutdict (ddtype in the code) objects, that basically work as a three-dimensional function, by mapping each couple of natural elements into a real number.

But if I try to use matplotlib to print all the elements with some characteristics:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

ddtype = defaultdict(int, {(1,1):2.2,(1,2):0.7,(2,1):0.9,(2,2):1.3})

for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,3):
        if (ddtype[i,j] > 1.5):
            plt.plot((i,j),'k+')

plt.show()
# The plot is saved but not here
```

then the program becomes very slow (for big ranged cycles) even though I clear the memory frequently. Is it there a more efficient way to write the above loop?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unpack the filtered `i` and `j` into separate containers, and then plot.

  - Processing the `defaultdict` separately, and then only plotting once, should be faster than accessing the plot object multiple times.
- Collect the desired tuples with a list comprehension:

  - `[k for k, v in ddtype.items() if v > 1.5]`
- Unpack the tuples into separate objects:

  - `i, j = zip(*[...])`
  - Referenced [Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7558990/7758804)

```py
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ddt = dd(int, {(1, 1): 2.2, (1, 2): 0.7, (2, 1): 0.9, (2, 2): 1.3})

i, j = zip(*[k for k, v in ddt.items() if v > 1.5])

plt.plot(i, j, 'k+')
```

[image]