# Multiple optional arguments python

Tags: python-3.x, optional-arguments

So I have a function with several optional arguments like so:

```
def func1(arg1, arg2, optarg1=None, optarg2=None, optarg3=None):
```

Optarg1 & optarg2 are *usually* used together and if these 2 args are specified then optarg3 is not used.  By contrast, if optarg3 is specified then optarg1 & optarg2 are not used.  If it were one optional argument it'd be easy for the function to "know" which argument to use:

```
if optarg1 != None:
    do something
else:
    do something else
```

My question is how to I "tell" the function which optional argument to use when there's multiple optional arguments and not all of them are always specified?  Is parsing the arguments with **kwargs the way to go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function with optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/function-with-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**kwargs is used to let Python functions take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments and then ** unpacks a dictionary of keyword arguments. [Learn More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

```
def print_keyword_args(**kwargs):
    # kwargs is a dict of the keyword args passed to the function
    print kwargs
    if("optarg1" in kwargs and "optarg2" in kwargs):
        print "Who needs optarg3!"
        print kwargs['optarg1'], kwargs['optarg2']
    if("optarg3" in kwargs):
        print "Who needs optarg1, optarg2!!"
        print kwargs['optarg3']

print_keyword_args(optarg1="John", optarg2="Doe")
# {'optarg1': 'John', 'optarg2': 'Doe'}
# Who needs optarg3!
# John Doe
print_keyword_args(optarg3="Maxwell")
# {'optarg3': 'Maxwell'}
# Who needs optarg1, optarg2!!
# Maxwell
print_keyword_args(optarg1="John", optarg3="Duh!")
# {'optarg1': 'John', 'optarg3': 'Duh!'}
# Who needs optarg1, optarg2!!
# Duh!
```

Comment: This is the most Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `kwargs` here? You might as well do `if optarg1 is not None and optarg2 is not None`... This way the arguments of the function are at least clear. Using `kwargs` exclusively, it is not clear what arguments it's even expecting...

Answer (score 18):

If you assign them in the call of the function you can pre-empt which parameter you are passing in.

```
def foo( a, b=None, c=None):
    print("{},{},{}".format(a,b,c))

>>> foo(4) 
4,None,None
>>> foo(4,c=5)
4,None,5
```