# How to skip the parameters of a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to skip parameters while calling a function. Could you please help me how to do this?

Example:

I have to call below function which is having 3 parameters:

```
send_mail(audit_df, LOG_FILE, Duration)
```

I have to call above function to skip 1st and 3rd parameters. How can i do this?

Comment: Are you writing that function, or is that function provided by someone else?

Comment: I am writing this function

Comment: Then read "Python default arguments".

Comment: And the other two have sensible defaults? What would you like those variables to be when you don't explicitly set a value?

Comment: Change it like this: ```send_mail( LOG_FILE,audit_df=DEFAULT_VALUE, Duration=DEFAULT_VALUE)``` and ignore them with DEFAULT_VALUE

Comment: If you are writing that function, use keyword arguments with default values. But that's just _basics_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup default values for the parameters. I don't know what works for you, so I just set them to `None`.

```
def send_mail(audit_df=None, log_file=None, duration=None):
    do all the things
```

when calling

```
send_mail(log_file="myfile")
```

For a little light reading see the [Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) section of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can place "None" in place of the parameter.

This is going to make python assume that it is Nothing and will do nothing.

Comment: Python will assign `None` to the variables but after that, its up to the code what to do. Its not that its nothing and python will do nothing, its that `None` is assigned and if the code doesn't handle that case, exceptions will ensue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways using

1. **kwargs
2. Optional parameters

See the answer below for details

[Multiple optional arguments python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279256/multiple-optional-arguments-python)