# Optional argument in class/function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I wonder if there are any good practices in python how to handle cases if I want to pass optional argument to function.

I have this function in class:

```
def gen(self, arg1, arg2, optional):
    if optional exists do that:
        print(optional)
    else:
        print(arg1, arg2)
```

What I can do right now is just handle that by if, but I don't think this is the best way to do that.

Comment: Based on your example, do you really ignore `arg1` and `arg2` if `optional` is present?

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass optional arguments to function consider using`*args` and `**kwargs` or just use default parameter.

e.g with `*args` and `**kwargs`

```
In [3]: def test(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:     print a, b, b
   ...:     if args:
   ...:         print args # do something, which is optional
   ...:     if kwargs:
   ...:         print kwargs # do something, which is optional
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]: test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6, 7, name='abc', place='xyz')
1 2 2
(4, 5, 6, 7)
{'place': 'xyz', 'name': 'abc'}

In [5]:
```

e.g. with default parameter.

```
def gen(self, arg1, arg2, optional=None):
    if optional:
        # do something
```