# Python - optional parameters before the required ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, logic

```
def func(a,  b,  c,  config)
```

I will always need to choose one of the three(a, b, c) and the config is always required. 
It should work like:

```
func(a="hello", config)
```

and

```
func(b="hello", config)
```

Is possible to place optional parameters before the required ones?

Comment: It aready has been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Python function with optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of default parameters.

```
def func(config, a = None, b = None, c = None):
    pass
func(config, b="B")
```

Use dictionary

```
params = {"config": myConfig, "b": valB}  # you want b here
def func(**params):
    config = params["config"]
    a = params.get("a")
    b = params.get("b")
    c = params.get("c")
func(params)
```

Edit: If you want config should always be the last, use it as

```
def func(a=None, b=None, c=None, config=None):
    pass
func(b=valB, config=myConfig)
```

Comment: i think you should unpack the dict

Comment: I wanted that config was the last paramter