# Python -> function -> if no value is provided for one of the variables

Tags: python

Python function that adds two numbers: a and b. Return a + 1, if no value is provided for b.

```
def sum(a,b):
    if b is None:
        return a + 1
    else:
        return a + b
print(sum(3,2))
```

I tried print(sum(2))

Then --> TypeError: sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

b == None? b is None? ... How can i fix it?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Python function with optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply a default value of `None` to `b`. Also, as noted by @vash_the_stampede, you should not use `sum` because that is a built-in function. Change to something like `my_sum`

```
def my_sum(a,b=None):
    if b is None:
        return a + 1
    else:
        return a + b


>>> print(my_sum(2))
3
```

Comment: Shouldn't we alter the function name from `sum` to a non built in function variable name

Comment: @sacul Thank you!! But I don't really understand the logic of "not b" in this case. "return a + 1 if b is None else a + b" makes sense to me. If b has a default value of None, then "not b" means "not None", right? so b has a value? If b has a value, it shouldn't return a + 1. Although the code runs perfectly but i am very confused. Could you explain a bit more? Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, I actually removed that and changed it back to `if b is None`, because `if not b` would still be satisfied otherwise. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: :) Now I understand much better!! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a default in your function signature.

```
def my_sum(a, b=None):
    return a + 1 if b is None else a + b
```

I also changed the name of the function to `my_sum` since `sum` is a builtin, and the condition to `b is None` because `not b` would be true if `b = 0` as well.

Comment: Thank for taking the time to explain !! Your time and knowledge is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

The shortest version:

```
def sum_ab(a, b=1):
    return a + b
```

Comment: Much better default. :)