# How can I pass 3 arguments being one of them an array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function where I will usually pass as arguments `Vm` and `Vp`, hoewever, in some cases I would like to add as well as an input parameter a `numpy.array`, called `Yin`.

```
def solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE(self,Vm,Vp,*,Yin=0):
```

In that case, I am facing up an issue when calling my function with Yin as 
a `numpy.arry` like the following one

```
ec_0_04 = numpy.array([
                      [0.00188453428035827 + 0.0124200286145695j],
                      [0.00188453428035827 + 0.0124200286145695j]
                      ])
for yin in ec_0_04:
        EC,C = pinsAsLine.solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE(-1,-1,*yin)
```

Then, Python complains with this error

```
    EC,C = pinsAsLine.solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE(-1,-1,numpy.array([0.00188453428035827 + 0.0124200286145695j]))
TypeError: solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I do understand the error, Python see four inputs to a function of three, but I am not sure how to properly pass my array as input to the function.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: bite me if i am wrong, but i think pinsAsLine is the 4th (or rather first) argument you pass. If solveTransmission.... is your method, add a 'this' before the other parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Python function with optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments)

Comment: Code does not match error message…

Comment: `solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE(-1,-1,yin)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the use of the `*`.

You declared your method like this:

```
def solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE(self,Vm,Vp,*,Yin=0):
```

Which means your function will take `self` as first arg, `Vm` and `Vp` as second and third. They are *positional arguments*. Then it will accept a **named argument** (or *keyword-only argument*): `Yin`.

In the end, you should call your method like this:

```
for yin in ec_0_04:
     EC,C = pinsAsLine.solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE(-1,-1,Yin=yin)
```

> By the way, I may be wrong but I don't think the `*` to be of any use in your method declaration.

Comment: by doing so I fixed the issue with the caller, but now internally in `solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE` I make use of `fsolve` which complains as `TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'CandGTransmissionLineDistributedE'.Shape should be (2,) but it is (2, 1).` How can I solve this?

Comment: I won't be able to tell without knowing what's inside your function... You should also know that you are giving `0` as a delault value for yin, but pass an array: this will probably causes you problems in the future

Comment: The function inside has a call like this `g,c = fsolve(self.CandGTransmissionLineDistributedE,self.initialGoCo,Yin)` where initialGoCo is an numpy.array of two elements

Comment: I don't know... Maybe you should post another question about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
for yin in ec_0_04:
        EC,C = pinsAsLine.solveTransmissionLineDistrbutedE(-1,-1,Yin=yin)
```

Pass the whole array as an argument.