# Need help to make an empty function

Tags: function

I want to make a function pi(d), where "d" tells how many decimals pi should return. If "d" is bigger than 15, it should include 15 decimals. If "d" is empty(pi(d)), pi should include 2 decimals. 
I have tried:

```
import math

def pi(x):
    if x>15:
        print(math.pi)
    elif x=="":
        print(round(math.pi, 2))
    else:
        print(round(math.pi, x))
```

What is wrong?

Comment: By empty, do you mean *omitted*, as in `pi()`? It might help if you include the complete text of your assignment in your question.

Comment: Yes, i mean omitted!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Python function with optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i mean omitted

So, you mean: [How do I create a Python function with optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments)

In your case:

```
def pi(x=2):
    if x>15:
        print(math.pi)
    else:
        print(round(math.pi, x))

pi()
```