# Two views with only one diffrent line of code

Tags: python, django

I have two views with only one diffrent line of code, rest is same in both views. How to prevent repetition of code? Can i delete tag_view and add optional parameter as kwarg to index and depending on it return view without specific tag or with tag? Is it how it should work? My views below.

```
def index(request):
    post_form = AddPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    comment_form = AddCommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # FORMULARZ DODAWANIA POSTU
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post_form.save()
            create_notifications(post_form.instance)

        # FORMULARZ DODAWANIA KOMENTARZA
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.save()

    (posts, comments) = serve_post_and_comments_except_blocked(request)

    return render(request, 'mikroblog/index.html', {'posts': posts, 'comments': comments,
                                                    'post_form': post_form, 'comment_form': comment_form})


def tag_view(request, tag):
    post_form = AddPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    comment_form = AddCommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # FORMULARZ DODAWANIA POSTU
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post_form.save()
            create_notifications(post_form.instance)

        # FORMULARZ DODAWANIA KOMENTARZA
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.save()

    (posts, comments) = serve_post_and_comments_except_blocked(request)
    posts.filter(content_post__contains=tag)
    actual_tag = tag

    return render(request, 'mikroblog/tag.html', {'posts': posts, 'actual_tag': actual_tag, 'comments': comments,
                                                  'post_form': post_form, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539921/how-do-i-create-a-python-function-with-optional-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define an helper function like this (not tested):

```
def view_common(url, request, tag=None):
    post_form = AddPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    comment_form = AddCommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # FORMULARZ DODAWANIA POSTU
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post_form.save()
            create_notifications(post_form.instance)

        # FORMULARZ DODAWANIA KOMENTARZA
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.save()

    (posts, comments) = serve_post_and_comments_except_blocked(request)
    posts.filter(content_post__contains=tag)

    parameters = {'posts': posts, 'comments': comments,'post_form': post_form, 'comment_form': comment_form}

    if tag:
        parameters['actual_tag'] = tag

    return render(request, url, parameters)
```

and then redefine your 2 functions like this:

```
def tag_view(request, tag):
    return view_common('mikroblog/tag.html', request, tag=tag)

def index(request):
    return view_common('mikroblog/index.html', request)
```

Hope this helps.