# Store a list of strings in one attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

I think I might not have explained my question clearly. I apologise for that. I will try again.

I have a parent class with certain attributes:

```
class Restaurant():
'This is the restaurant class'

def __init__(self, name, cuisine_type):
    self.name = name
    self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
```

Then I have a child class inheriting all the parent's attributes and adding a new one:

```
class IceCreamStand():

def __init__(self, *flavor):
    'Attributes of parent class initialised'
    self.flavor = flavor
```

Now I try printing a list of of flavours stored in the attribute flavor:

```
def desc_flavor(self):
    print('This Ice_Cream shop has ' + self.flavor + ' flavors')

flavor1 = IceCreamStand('Mango', 'Raspberry', 'Coffee', 'Vanilla')
```

If I use concat I get the message saying that the name is not defined.

My apologies for not explaining the problem correctly the first time and thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
def __init__(self, *attribute1):
    self.atributte1 = attribute1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
      def __init__(self,restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
          super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
         
      def describe_flavors(self,*flavors):
          print(f'{self.restaurant_name} has the following flavors:')
          for self.flavor in flavors:
              print(f'-{self.flavor}')
           
restaurant =IceCreamStand('DQ','ice cream')
restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.describe_flavors('Chocolate','Mango', 'Raspberry', 'Coffee', 'Vanilla')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Arbitrary argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539977/5735010) answer.

Example:

```
li = []
def example(*arg):
    li = list(arg)
    print(li)

example('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
```

Answer (score -2):

As far I know you are doing exercise of chapter 9 from the book of Python Crash Course. This is the code which I did as its part of another exercise. Hope this helps you.

```
class Restaurant():
"""A simple attempt to model a restaurant."""

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cusisine_type):
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.type = cusisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("Restaurant name is " + self.name.title() + ".")
        # print(self.name.title() + " is a " + self.type + " type restaurant.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(self.name.title() + " is open!")


class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
"""Making a class that inherits from Restaurant parent class."""

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cusisine_type):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cusisine_type)
        self.flavor = 'chocolate'

    def display_flavors(self):
        print("This icrecream shop has " + self.flavor + " flavor.")


# create an instance of IceCreamStand
falvors = IceCreamStand('baskin robbins', 'icecream')

# print("My restaurant name is: " + falvors.name)
# print("Restaurant is which type: " + falvors.type)
falvors.describe_restaurant()
falvors.open_restaurant()

# Calling this method
falvors.display_flavors()
```