# Optional field requires a necessary value

Tags: python, typing, pydantic

I have a function with optional field **url**

```
def create_ads_task(
    template_id: int,
    ad_account_id: str,
    adset_ids: List[str],
    placements: Dict[str, str],
    locales: List[Locale],
    url: Optional[HttpUrl],
) -> List[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]:
    ...body...
```

When I run the tests, I get an error

```
E       TypeError: create_ads_task() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

**test.py**

```
assert create_ads_task(
    TEMPLATE_ID, AD_ACCOUNT_ID, ADSET_IDS, PLACEMENTS, LOCALES
) == [ ..... ]
```

How to fix test I now, but I cant understand why optional field is required. The function does not always need the url parameter, sometimes it is not passed from the frontend. How do I define the optional parameter correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Optional[..]` says that the parameter passed **SHOULD BE** of the mentioned type OR `None`, like in your case `url` should be of type `HttpUrl` OR `None`, but it does not mean that if it's not passed it will carry a default value. See the below example:

```
from typing import Optional

# In this b will should be passed as str or None
def test_with_optional(a: str, b: Optional[str]):
    print (a,b)
    
# In this if b is not passed, it will carry a default value of None
def test_with_none(a: str, b: str=None):
    print (a,b)
    
test_with_optional('1', None)
test_with_none('2')
```

`test_with_optional('1')` will throw error `TypeError: test_with_optional() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'` because what it expects b either as a `string` or as `None`.

For your case your definition will be as below. Read more about optional parameters [here](https://realpython.com/python-optional-arguments/#using-python-optional-arguments-with-default-values)

```
def create_ads_task(
        template_id: int,
        ad_account_id: str,
        adset_ids: List[str],
        placements: Dict[str, str],
        locales: List[Locale],
        url: Optional[HttpUrl]=None,
    ) -> List[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]:
        ...body...
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But my question about `typing` mostly. Why Optional  doesn't actually make the parameter optional

Comment: `Optional[HttpUrl]` says that `url` SHOULD BE of type `HttpUrl` OR `None`, it does not say that if nothing is passed treat it as `None`

Answer (score 1):

Type hinting that it is optional is not enough. You have to assign a default value to it. Like:

```
def create_ads_task(
    template_id: int,
    ad_account_id: str,
    adset_ids: List[str],
    placements: Dict[str, str],
    locales: List[Locale],
    url: Optional[HttpUrl] = None,
) -> List[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]:
    ...body...
```

Comment: So, type `Optional` doesn't  guarantee and always have to specify a default value ?

Comment: No. In `python` to have an optional parameter you basically assign a default value to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67103403/2681662 Type hinting is just, well, for hinting.

Comment: What's the point of `Optianal` type if it doesn't actually make the parameter optional ?Just indicates that the parameter may not exist?

Comment: And BTW `Optional` means the parameter has a default value. It doesn't mean it may not exist. Usually you assign `None` and parse it in the function itself if it might not exist. TL;DR an optional parameter exist but has a default value.

Comment: And https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp we can see these parameters are called DEFAULT not optional. Maybe it's just an unfortunate naming?