# Python 3: starred expression to unpack a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, argument-unpacking

Example use:

```
def f(a, b, c, d): 
    print(a, b, c, d, sep = '&')

f(1,2,3,4)
>>> 1&2&3&4

f(*[1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> 1&2&3&4
```

Where in the python documentation is `*` explained?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/getting-python-sequence-assignments-unpacking-right

Comment: The relevant portion of the language reference is here: http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#calls .  Look for the sentence starting "If the syntax *expression appears in the function call"

Comment: Good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `*args` calling convention is documented in the [Expressions reference](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, `expression` must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are positional arguments *x1, ..., xN*, and `expression` evaluates to a sequence *y1, ..., yM*, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional arguments *x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM*.

So, since you used `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as the expression, which is an iterable, and there were no other positional arguments, it is treated as a call with M=0 and N=4, for a total of 4 positional arguments.

You can thus also call your function as `f(1, 2, *[3, 4])` or any other combination of iterable and positional arguments, provided the iterable comes *after* the positionals.

Answer (score 9):

Just an addition to very simply expand on the combination of unnamed and named arguments.

This is the general order you want to keep in mind:

```
def func(arg_1, ..., arg_N, *args, kwarg_1, ..., kwarg_M, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
    return True
```

Where, in most typical cases;

- each single `arg_i` is an unnamed argument,
- `args` is a list, hence a set of unnamed arguments,
- each single `kwarg_j` is a named argument,
- `kwargs` is a dictionary, hence a set of named arguments.