# How to join two sets in one line without using "|"

Tags: python, set

Assume that `S` and `T` are assigned sets. Without using the join operator `|`, how can I find the union of the two sets? This, for example, finds the intersection:

```
S = {1, 2, 3, 4}
T = {3, 4, 5, 6}
S_intersect_T = { i for i in S if i in T }
```

So how can I find the union of two sets in one line without using `|`?

Comment: do you need to union? If yes then you can do s.union(t)

Comment: Why can't you use `|`?

Comment: Any generic reason not to use `|` ?

Comment: One reason might be passing a set operation as a function argument. Imagine a function, something like: `def apply_set_operation(a, b, set_operation)`. When calling this function, I'd prefer `apply_set_operation(a, b, set.union)` to `apply_set_operation(a, b, set.__or__)`

Comment: What's the use case for a function to abstract set operations? Why not just do `a | b` instead of calling a function to do that?

Answer (score 377):

You can use union method for sets: `set.union(other_set)`

Note that it returns a new set i.e it doesn't modify itself.

Comment: However, `|` can modify the variable inline: `set_a |= set_b`

Comment: @jorgenkg same as: `set_a = set_a.union(set_b)`. If you mean "in-place", neither will do that, both create a new `set`

Comment: @nitely no, using `|=` will modify the variable `a` inline

Comment: @jorgenkg it still creates a new set and replaces the reference.

Comment: @Alvaro @nitely according to a simple test: `a = set((1, 2, 3,)); b = set((1, 3, 4,)); id_a = id(a); a |= b; assert id_a == id(a)`, @jorgenkg is right - variable `a` is modified inline. Am I missing something?

Comment: @johndodo what you are missing is that when the single line is executed, in general two things happen: 1. the set represented by `a` is destroyed, and 2. the variable `a` then refers to the newly created set in its place. in THIS case the old and new set have the same id because they are identical and the set is very simple, so python efficiently kept the old alive internally for use later.

Comment: Nope, doesn't look like it: `a = set((1, 2, 3,)); b = set((1, 3, 4,)); c = a; a |= b; assert id(c) == id(a)`. Even if `a` was destroyed, `c` wouldn't have been. Also, `c` is now `set([1, 2, 3, 4])`, so @jorgenkg's comment is correct.

Comment: Note that `set.union` can be called statically: `new_set = set.union(first_set, second_set)`, for example, or `set.union(*collection_of_sets)`.

Comment: `set_both = set_a.union(set_b)` would be a clearer example, and would suggest that the [union method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) creates a new set but does not mutate the instance in place. The example given could never work, because `set` is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 62):

You could use `or_` alias:

```
>>> from operator import or_
>>> from functools import reduce # python3 required
>>> reduce(or_, [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 6}])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: love this approach, more functional, and could be applied to 2 or more sets.

Answer (score 58):

If you are fine with modifying the original set (which you may want to do in some cases), you can use `set.update()`:

```
S.update(T)
```

The return value is `None`, but `S` will be updated to be the union of the original `S` and `T`.

Answer (score 30):

Assuming you also can't use `s.union(t)`, which is equivalent to `s | t`, you could try

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain(s,t))
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Or, if you want a comprehension,

```
>>> {i for j in (s,t) for i in j}
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 23):

You can just unpack both sets into one like this:

```py
>>> set_1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> set_2 = {3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> union = {*set_1, *set_2}
>>> union
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

The `*` unpacks the set. Unpacking is where an iterable (e.g. a set or list) is represented as every item it yields. This means the above example simplifies to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6}` which then simplifies to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` because the set can only contain unique items.

Comment: What does the `*` do in line 3?

Comment: @altabq He answers what starred expressions are in the answer. Also try playing with it in the REPL. See what `print(set_1)` vs. `print(*set_1)` looks like. Also this may give you more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555627/python-3-starred-expression-to-unpack-a-list

Comment: Thanks @aaron-bell, the answer was edited after I posted my comment to include the explanation.

Answer (score 18):

If by join you mean union, try this:

```
set(list(s) + list(t))
```

It's a bit of a hack, but I can't think of a better one liner to do it.

Comment: set(list(s) + list(t)) will give you the same the result if you will do a union.

Comment: I'm aware, but it looks like he was trying to avoid using built in python functions, otherwise he would have just used the | operator.

Comment: `list` and `set` are built in python functions

Answer (score 14):

Suppose you have 2 lists

```
 A = [1,2,3,4]
 B = [3,4,5,6]
```

so you can find `A` Union `B` as follow

```
 union = set(A).union(set(B))
```

also if you want to find intersection and non-intersection you do that as follow

```
 intersection = set(A).intersection(set(B))
 non_intersection = union - intersection
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do `union` or simple list comprehension

```
[A.add(_) for _ in B]
```

A would have all the elements of B

Comment: using list comprehension for side effects and with anonymous param is super bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to join `n` sets, the best performance seems to be from `set().union(*list_of_sets)`, which will return a new set.

Thus, the usage might be:

```py
s1 = {1, 2, 3}
s2 = {2, 3, 4}
s3 = {4, 5, 6}

s1.union(s2, s3) # returns a new set
# Out: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
s1.update(s2, s3) # updates inplace
```

Adding to [Alexander Klimenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027490/14403987)'s answer above, I did some simple testing as shown below. I believe the main takeaway is that it seems like the **more random** the sets are, the **bigger the difference** on performance.

```py
from random import randint

n = 100

generate_equal = lambda: set(range(10_000))
generate_random = lambda: {randint(0, 100_000) for _ in range(10_000)}

for l in [
    [generate_equal() for _ in range(n)],
    [generate_random() for _ in range(n)]
]:
    %timeit set().union(*l)
    %timeit reduce(or_, l)
```

```
Out:
  # equal sets: 69.5 / 23.6 =~ 3
  23.6 ms ± 658 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  69.5 ms ± 2.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  # random sets: 438 / 78.7 =~ 5.6
  78.7 ms ± 1.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  438 ms ± 20.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Therefore, if you want to update inplace, the best performance comes from `set.update` method, as, performance wise, `s1.update(s2, s3) = set().union(s2, s3)`.