# Text Mining: Query search

Tags: python, text-mining

I have a dictionary:

```
{'Farage': [0, 5, 9, 192,233,341],
 'EU': [0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 23]}

Query1: “Farage” and “EU”
Query2: “Farage” or “EU”
```

I need to return the documents that contain these queries. For query1, for example, the answer should be [0,5,9].
I believe the answer should be something like that but in python:

```
final_list = []
while x≠Null and y≠Null
    do if docID(x)=docID(y)
       then ADD(final_list, docID(x))
          x← next(x)
          y ←next(y)
        else if docID(x) < docID(y)
          then x← next(x)
          else y ←next(y)
return final_list
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to write code that gets both results?

Comment: Yes! I would like to extract both results depending on the user inserting AND or OR in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `dict` of operators and throw `set` operations to get the final results. It assumes that queries follow strict rule of `key1 operator key2 operator key3`

For arbitrary number of arguments

```
import operator
d1={'Farage': [0, 5, 9, 192,233,341],
    'EU': [0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 23],
    'hopeless': [0, 341, 19999]}

d={'and':operator.and_,
  'or':operator.or_}

Queries= ['Farage and EU','Farage and EU or hopeless','Farage or EU']

for query in Queries:
    res=set()
    temp_arr = query.split()
    k1 = temp_arr[0]

    for value in range(1,len(temp_arr),2):
        op = temp_arr[value]
        k2 = temp_arr[value+1]
        if res:
            res = d[op](res, set(d1.get(k2, [])))
        else:
            res = d[op](set(d1.get(k1, [])), set(d1.get(k2, [])))
    print(res)
```

Output

```
set([0, 9, 5])
set([0, 192, 5, 233, 9, 19999, 341])
set([0, 192, 5, 6, 1, 233, 23, 341, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own function using [`sets`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set), a structure that Python provides and works best for your case by speeding up the process of [joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429123/how-to-join-two-sets-in-one-line-without-using) and [intersecting](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection) sequences of elements:

```
def getResults(s, argument):
    s = list(s.values())
    if argument == 'OR':
        result = s[0]
        for elem in s[1:]:
            result = sorted(set(result).union(set(elem)))
        return result
    elif argument == 'AND':
        result = s[0]
        for elem in s[1:]:
            result = sorted(set(result).intersection(set(elem)))
        return result
    else:
        return None

inDict = {'Farage': [0, 5, 9, 192,233,341], 'EU': [0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 23]}

query1 = getResults(inDict, 'AND')
query2 = getResults(inDict, 'OR')

print(query1)
print(query2)
```

Results:

```
[0, 5, 9]
[0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 23, 192, 233, 341]
```

Note: You can remove the `sorted` function if you do not want any sorting.

Comment: So you want to join and intersect all these objects?

Comment: You solved my example and thanks a lot. But I forgot to mention that in my real case I have thousands of objects in the dictionary and I don't know exactly where the words I search for are located or if they exist at all. 
ex:{'hopeless': [0, 341, 19999],'tomorrow': [0,200,242,301,398,568,712], 'sad':[1,3,5,6,8,9,18,...], 'work': [13,20,45,129,...] ,etc...]
what I am tryingt to say is that I have more then s1 and s2. How could I solve this?

Comment: @jroc Edited my question, you can try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind, use the conversion into sets:

```
>>> d = {'Farage': [0, 5, 9, 192, 233, 341] , 'EU': [0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 23]}
>>> d
{'EU': [0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 23], 'Farage': [0, 5, 9, 192, 233, 341]}
>>>
>>> set(d['EU']) | set(d['Farage'])
{0, 1, 192, 5, 6, 9, 233, 341, 23}
>>>
>>> set(d['EU']) & set(d['Farage'])
{0, 9, 5}
>>>
>>> set(d['EU']) ^ set(d['Farage'])
{192, 1, 23, 233, 341, 6}
>>>
>>> set(d['EU']) - set(d['Farage'])
{1, 6, 23}
```

Or change the format of the input if it is possible for the dictionary to be directly in the form of the set, that is:

```
>>> d = {'Farage': {0, 5, 9, 192, 233, 341}, 'EU': {0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 23}}
>>> d['EU'] & d['Farage']
{0, 9, 5}
```