# unpickle list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file that has some dicts and list that I pickle (roughly 900 lines) that I don't want in my main script.  I then do the following.

```
myDicts = [DictOne, DictTwo, ListOne, ListTwo]
pickle.dump(myDicts, open("all.p", "wb"))
```

this creates the all.p file which I load in my script.

```
myDicts = pickle.load( open ("all.p", "rb") )
```

What I don't know is how to access these Dictionaries now.  How do I use the imported dictionaries?  I can print the length or the entire list so I know the data is there, but I have no clue on how to access it, checked out some of the post here but I can't figure it out.

I tried

I would normally do something like this:

```
if blah == "blah" and sum([x in "text" for x in DictOne]):
```

so I tried doing this:

```
if blah == "blah" and sum([x in "text" for x in myDicts(DictOne)]):
```

Is there a easy way to just save the dictionary/list back to a dictionary/list?

```
DictOne = myDicts('DictOne')
ListOne = myDicts('ListOne')
```

or if I have

```
if flaga:
   list=mydicts('ListOne')
elif flagb:
   list=mydicts('ListTwo')
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead of a list to store all of your sub-containers, and retrieve them with the appropriate keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily unpack values like this:

```
DictOne, DictTwo, *_ = pickle.load( open ("all.p", "rb") )
```

Instead of `*_` you can add the next `ListOne`, `ListTwo` if you need.

Note: For using `*_` you will need Python 3.x.x

Comment: The `*_` statement is explained further here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555627/python-3-starred-expression-to-unpack-a-list

Comment: Thanks this is nice and easy to understand.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you pickled your original list, you can access the objects stored in that list by referencing their index in the list.  So if you want to get `DictTwo`, you can call `myDicts[1]` (because you count starting at 0).

If you want to be able to call it using a string-based name, you can make the original container a dictionary instead of a list (as @MackM suggests in a comment):

```
myDicts = {"DictOne": DictOne, "DictTwo": DictTwo, "ListOne": ListOne, "ListTwo": ListTwo}
```

You might want to read up on calling basic python [data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).