# sum of N lists element-wise python

Tags: python, list, sum

Is there an easy way to compute the element-wise sum of N lists in python? I know if we have n lists *defined* (call the ith list `c_i`), we can do:

```
z = [sum(x) for x in zip(c_1, c_2, ...)]
```

For example:

```
c1 = [1,2]
c2 = [3,4]
c3 = [5,6]
z  = [sum(x) for x in zip(c1,c2,c3)]
```

Here `z = [9, 12]`

But what if we don't have `c_i` defined and instead have `c_1...c_n` in a list `C`?

Is there a similar way to find `z` if we just have `C`?

I hope this is clear.

resolved: I was wondering what the * operator was all about...thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just do this:

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*C)]
```

In the above, `C` is the list of `c_1...c_n`. As explained in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python) in the comments (thanks, @kevinsa5!):

> `*` is the "splat" operator: It takes a list as input, and expands it into actual positional arguments in the function call.

For additional details, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), under "unpacking argument lists" and also read about [calls](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) (thanks, @abarnert!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python Shows what the asterisk does. I didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: Didn't some spoilsport go through and remove all references to the name "splat" anywhere in the docs somewhere around 2.5 or 2.6/3.0? Anyway, the tutorial section is ["Unpacking Argument Lists"](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and the reference is [Calls](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Comment: Very nice and pythonic!

Comment: does this only work for integers and because it breaks when I try it with floats.

Comment: @Roshini of course it works with floats, you must be doing something wrong, it's just an addition! check the way you're building the input lists.

Comment: I tried your method, but it keeps giving me this message: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 2):

This isn't all that different from Óscar López's answer, but uses `itertools.imap` instead of a list comprehension.

```
from itertools import imap
list(imap(sum, zip(*C))
```

Comment: works only for Python 2, `imap` was removed in Python 3