# python element wise add in list of list with other list

Tags: python, numpy

I checked similar problem at [sum of N lists element-wise python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261747/sum-of-n-lists-element-wise-python)

but mine is a little bit more complicate cause I am adding list of list with another list of list

my list looks like it below

```
[[0         0.014285714 0.035600016]
,[0.014285714   0           0.038359389]
,[0.035600016   0.038359389 0]]


[[0         0.014285714 0.035600016]
,[0.014285714   0           0.038359389]
,[0.035600016   0.038359389 0]]
```

so adding these two then results has 3 by 3 matrix

how could I efficiently add these two lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can i solve using numpy:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> b = [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]

>>> from numpy import array, sum

>>> list(array(a) + array(b))
[array([5, 7, 9]), array([5, 7, 9]), array([5, 7, 9])]
```

OR

```
>>> sum([a, b], axis=0)
 array([[5, 7, 9],
       [5, 7, 9],
       [5, 7, 9]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with numpy matrices, @AlexThornton has the best answer

If you are dealing with lists, you should do:

```
summed_list = [[c+d for c,d in zip(i,j)] for i,j in zip(a,b)]   #a,b are your two lists
```

#### Simple example:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
>>> b = [[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]

>>> summed_list = [[c+d for c,d in zip(i,j)] for i,j in zip(a,b)]   #a,b are your two lists

>>> print summed_list
[[5,7,9],
 [5,7,9],
 [5,7,9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You tagged your question `numpy`, so I assume this is OK:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix(a)
b = np.matrix(b)
c = a + b
```

Where `a` and `b` are your two lists, and `c` is the two added together.

By far the simplest with `numpy`. :)

Comment: It is advisable to avoid the matrix class unless you specifically want the caveats of the matrix class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution using 'vanilla' python and recursion
(This solution works for nested tuples or lists)

```
from operator import add
def list_recur(l1, l2, op = operator.add):
    if not l1:
        return type(l1)([])
    elif isinstance(l1[0], type(l1)):
        return type(l1)([list_recur(l1[0], l2[0], op)]) + \
list_recur(l1[1:],l2[1:], op)
    else:
        return type(l1)([op(l1[0], l2[0])]) + \
list_recur(l1[1:], l2[1:], op)
```

This solution takes arguments list1, list2 and optionally the operation you want to perform `element-wise` (*by default addition*).

*For example,* `list_recur([ [1, 2, 3, [4, 5] ], [1, 2, 3, [4, 5] ])` will return `[ [2, 4, 6, [8, 10] ]`.

*More complex examples will work too:*

`list_recur([[[[[1,[[[[2, 3]]]]]]]], [[[[3, [[[[4, 1]]]]]]]], lambda x, y: \
x < y)` will return `[[[[True, [[[[True, False]]]]]]]]`
`