# how to zip function with two arrays as a return value - Python

Tags: python, function, zip

how do I create tuple from two randomly generated lists with separate function ? zip function will create only tuple of those two arrays as whole but I need the numbers to be coupled like (1,2),(3,4). Thanks.

```
import random
def ars():
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    for i in range(10):
        x = random.randrange(100)
        arr1.append(x)
    for j in range(10):
        y = random.randrange(100)
        arr2.append(y)
    return(arr1,arr2)

x = ars()
print x
y = zip(ars())
print y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) accepts multiple iterables as its arguments, so you simply have to [unpack the values](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) from the returned tuple with `*` (splat operator):

```
y = zip(*ars())
```

With `zip(([1], [2]))` only one iterable is submitted (that tuple).

In `zip(*([1], [2]))` you unpack 2 lists from tuple, so `zip` receives 2 iterables.

Comment: Ah, you turned green, I see.

Comment: * is the "splat" operator: It takes a list as input, and expands it into actual positional arguments in the function call. Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python

Comment: @thefourtheye, you liked the old avatar? :)

Comment: @SkyDive you can also do `**some_dict` to unpack key->value pairs from `some_dict` to the keyword arguments.

Comment: Who doesn't like the GO Green avatar ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid having to zip by using map

```
def ars(arr_len, rand_max):
    return [map(random.randrange, [rand_max]*2) for x in range(arr_len)]
```

call ars like: ars(10,100), if you really need tuples instead of lists, wrap the map statement in a tuple() function.