# How do you create a dictionary from nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I was hoping that there might be someway to use a comprehension to do this, but say I have data that looks like this:

```
data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

My ultimate goal is to create a dictionary where the first nested list holds the keys and the remaining lists hold the values:

```
{'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

I have tried something like this that gets me close, but as you can tell I am having trouble appending the list in the dictionary values and this code is just overwriting:

```
d = {data[0][c]: [] + [col] for r, row in enumerate(data) for c, col in enumerate(row)}
>>> d
{'c': [6], 'a': [4], 'b': [5]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use zip in a dict comprehension:

```
{z[0]: list(z[1:3]) for z in zip(*data)}
Out[16]: {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

### How it works:

zip will take the *transpose*:

```
list(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
Out[19]: [('a', 1, 4), ('b', 2, 5), ('c', 3, 6)]
```

However, your data is a list of lists, so in order to make sure Python doesn't see a single list but sees three seperate lists, you need `zip(*data)` instead of `zip(data)`. There are several posts on the use of `*`: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python).

```
list(zip(*data))
Out[13]: [('a', 1, 4), ('b', 2, 5), ('c', 3, 6)]
```

And in the dict comprehension you are taking the first elements as the keys and the remaining two as the values.