# List elements to time format and calculate the time diff from today

Tags: python, html, datetime, time, format

I am using python 3.6 and got some problems to calculate date.

I have a list composed of date elements like below:

```
dates = [['2017','01','15'], ['2017','01','14'], ['2017','01','13'],...]
```

I would like to make it to time format and calculate the days from today.

How can I fix my code?

Below is my code:

```
dates = [['2017', '01', '15'], ['2017', '01', '14'], ['2017', '01', '13']]

for date in dates:
    date_cand = "-".join(date)
    date_cand_time = time.strptime(date_cand,"%Y-%m-%d")
    (datetime.date.today() - datetime.date(date_cand_time)).days
```

I have this error message now:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type time.struct_time)
```

The result that I would like to have is:

```
4
5
6
```

Please help me to work this out.

Answer (score 5):

`date_cand_time` is not an integer, it is a *tuple* with integers. You can't just pass that to the `datetime.date()` object. You'd have to pass in the first 3 elements as separate arguments instead:

```
(datetime.date.today() - datetime.date(*date_cand_time[:3])).days
```

The `*` tells Python to apply the values of the `lst_reg_date_cand_time[:3]` expression as separate arguments.

However, I'd not take a detour via `time.strptime()`; just map the 3 strings to integers and pass them in directly:

```
date_cand = datetime.date(*map(int, date))
(datetime.date.today() - date_cand).days
```

The arguments to `datetime.date()` are, after all, `year`, `month` and `day`, in the same order you have your strings.

If you *must* use `strptime`, then use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and extract the `date` object from that:

```
date_cand = datetime.datetime.strptime("-".join(date), "%Y-%m-%d")
(datetime.date.today() - date_cand.date()).days
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dates = [['2017','01','15'], ['2017','01','14'], ['2017','01','13']]
>>> for date in dates:
...     # using map, produces a date
...     date_cand = datetime.date(*map(int, date))
...     print(date_cand, (datetime.date.today() - date_cand).days)
...     # using datetime.datetime.strptime, produces a datetime
...     date_cand = datetime.datetime.strptime("-".join(date), "%Y-%m-%d")
...     print(date_cand, (datetime.date.today() - date_cand.date()).days)
...
2017-01-15 4
2017-01-15 00:00:00 4
2017-01-14 5
2017-01-14 00:00:00 5
2017-01-13 6
2017-01-13 00:00:00 6
```

Comment: In case people are wondering, *map(int,date) maps date into type int. Effectively converts date strings into ints. * operator then splat the list into positional arguments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python

Answer (score 4):

This code seems to work. Note that I use `datetime.strptime` instead of `time.strptime`, in case that makes any difference:

```
from datetime import datetime


def parse_dates(dates_array):
    today = datetime.today()
    for date_array in dates_array:
        date = datetime.strptime('-'.join(date_array), '%Y-%m-%d')
        yield (today - date).days


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = [['2017', '01', '15'], ['2017', '01', '14'], ['2017', '01', '13']]
    for days_from_today in parse_dates(dates):
        print(days_from_today)
```

**Output**

```
4
5
6
```

**Caveat**

I move the calculation of `today` outside the for loop for minor performance benefits, but this will cause the code to break if you leave this code running past midnight. :)

Answer (score 2):

This Python 2 / Python 3 code is a combination of Martijn's and Tagc's answers.

```
from datetime import datetime

def parse_dates(dates_array):
    today = datetime.today()
    for d in dates_array:
        yield (today - datetime(*map(int, d))).days

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = [
        ['2017', '01', '15'], 
        ['2017', '01', '14'], 
        ['2017', '01', '13'],
    ]
    for d in parse_dates(dates):
        print(d)
```

**output**

```
4
5
6
```

As Tagc said, if the date may change while this code is running then you need to move `today = datetime.today()` inside the `for` loop.

---

Here's essentially the same thing, without a function:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
    ['2017', '01', '15'], 
    ['2017', '01', '14'], 
    ['2017', '01', '13'],
]

today = datetime.today()

for d in dates:
    delta = (today - datetime(*map(int, d))).days
    print(delta)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since datetime.date was using in your code for delta calculation, here is a clean way of doing what you want.

```
import datetime 
dates = [['2017', '01', '15'], ['2017', '01', '14'], ['2017', '01', '13']]
today = datetime.date.today()
for date in dates:
    year,month,day = [int(s) for s in date] #convert to int and assign to vars : year, month, day
    date_cand_time = datetime.date(year,month,day) #convert date to datetime.date
    delta = (today - date_cand_time).days #calculate the day delta
    print delta
```

Output

```
4
5
6
```