# Meshgrid a N-columned matrix in Numpy (or smth else)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datagrid

**Python version**: 2.7

I have the following `numpy` 2d array:

```
array([[ -5.05000000e+01,  -1.05000000e+01],
   [ -4.04000000e+01,  -8.40000000e+00],
   [ -3.03000000e+01,  -6.30000000e+00],
   [ -2.02000000e+01,  -4.20000000e+00],
   [ -1.01000000e+01,  -2.10000000e+00],
   [  7.10542736e-15,  -1.77635684e-15],
   [  1.01000000e+01,   2.10000000e+00],
   [  2.02000000e+01,   4.20000000e+00],
   [  3.03000000e+01,   6.30000000e+00],
   [  4.04000000e+01,   8.40000000e+00]])
```

If I wanted to find all the combinations of the first and the second columns, I would use `np.array(np.meshgrid(first_column, second_column)).T.reshape(-1,2)`. As a result, I would get a `100*1 matrix` with `10*10 = 100 data points`. However, my matrix can have 3, 4, or more columns, so I have a problem of using this `numpy` function.

**Question**: how can I make an automatically meshgridded matrix with 3+ columns?

**UPD**: for example, I have the initial array:

```
[[-50.5 -10.5]
 [  0.    0. ]]
```

As a result, I want to have the output array like this:

```
array([[-10.5, -50.5],
   [-10.5,   0. ],
   [  0. , -50.5],
   [  0. ,   0. ]])
```

or this:

```
array([[-50.5, -10.5],
   [-50.5,   0. ],
   [  0. , -10.5],
   [  0. ,   0. ]])
```

Comment: By `3, 4, or more dimensional`, do you mean having `3, 4, or more number of columns` rather? To clarify that could you add sample for 3 "dimensional" data? Also, `np.meshgrid(first_column, second_column)` would give you a list of two arrays each having 100 elems. So, how would you have that `100*1 matrix`?

Comment: @Divakar, yes, you are right. I will update my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`*` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python) on the transposed array version that unpacks those columns sequentially. Finally, a swap axes operation is needed to merge the output grid arrays as one array.

Thus, one generic solution would be -

```
np.swapaxes(np.meshgrid(*arr.T),0,2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: arr
Out[44]: 
array([[-50.5, -10.5],
       [  0. ,   0. ]])

In [45]: np.swapaxes(np.meshgrid(*arr.T),0,2)
Out[45]: 
array([[[-50.5, -10.5],
        [-50.5,   0. ]],

       [[  0. , -10.5],
        [  0. ,   0. ]]])
```

Comment: I am afraid that does not work well. If I have a 2x2 matrix like this:

        [[-50.5 -10.5]
         [  0.    0. ]]

After typing `X_total = np.meshgrid(*X_total.T)` I would get:

        [array([[-50.5,   0. ],
        [-50.5,   0. ]]), array([[-10.5, -10.5],
        [  0. ,   0. ]])]

Instead I want:

        array([[-10.5, -50.5],
       [-10.5,   0. ],
       [  0. , -50.5],
       [  0. ,   0. ]])