# Use a formatted string to separate groups of digits

Tags: python, string-formatting

Given a number like `12345678910` I want to output `number id 123.456.789-10`.

I tried this:

```
print('number id {0:1.3}.{0:1.3}.{0:1.3}-{0:1.3}'.format("12345678910"))
```

but the result is `number id 123.123.123-123`. How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to achieve what you are looking to do:

```
number = "12345678910"
print(
    'number id {0}.{1}.{2}-{3}'.format(
        *[number[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(number), 3)]
    )
)
#number id 123.456.789-10.
```

There are a few problems with your code. First the first number in the `"{0...}"` refers to the positional argument in the `format()` function. In your case, you were using all `0` which refers to the first argument only. This is why the same substring was being repeated over and over. (Notice how I changed it to `{0}.{1}...{3}`.)

I am passing `*[number[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(number), 3)]` to the format function, which just breaks your string into chunks of 3.

```
print([number[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(number), 3)])
#['123', '456', '789', '10']
```

The `*` operator does [argument unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239873/5858851), which passes the elements of the list in order to `format()`.

---

**Update**:

As @user2357112 [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067307/in-python-how-i-represent-like-this/50067442?noredirect=1#comment87151515_50067442), you don't actually need anything inside the braces in this case. Just use `{}` to represent placeholders.

```
print(
    'number id {}.{}.{}-{}'.format(
        *[number[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(number), 3)]
    )
)
```