# What is the solution for this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was expecting different answer like 
0
1
3
6
But the answer is only 6.Could someone help me understand it please, Thanks!

```
def func(x):
  res = 0
  for i in range(x):
     res += i
  return res

print(func(4))
```

Comment: the print prints  whatever your function  returns. unless you `yield` the function can only return _one_ value. Why would it print 0 1 3 6 ? - you would need to print _inside_ the loop the actual `res` (before incrementing) to get these numbers, but then they'll be on seperate lines unless you specify `end=" "` for your print... - your function does essentially a `return sum(range(x))`

Comment: You add up the numbers in `range(4)` and get `0+1+2+3==6`. How did you expect it to work?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements for a short overview about `for` and ``range`

Comment: thanks guys, I appreciate deeply!

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns only one value. What you meant to use is `yield`:

```
def func(x):
  res = 0
  for i in range(x):
     res += i
     yield res
```

This is called a  [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). You may use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to see values one by one, or use [*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/asterisk-in-function-call) operator to print them all at once:

```
print(*(func(4)))
```

Sure enough, you get the desired output:

```
0 1 3 6
```

Comment: thanks. but I am new to python. can you explain it in simple way please. thanks.

Comment: @Bekry A `generator` is like an iterable, but generates (yields) elements on demand. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python) for more on the topic.