# Combinations from list of lists

Tags: python

I want to get all the possible combinations like so:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5]
c = [-1]

print(list(product(a, b, c)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4, -1), (1, 5, -1), (2, 4, -1), (2, 5, -1), (3, 4, -1), (3, 5, -1)]
```

However, I have all my lists stored inside a list:

```
s = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [-1]]

print(list(product(s)))
```

Output:

```
[([1, 2, 3],), ([4, 5],), ([-1],)]
```

I've previously tried unpacking the list, but I've only been able to create one big list, or a dictionary. Is there another way of unpacking the list or getting the product in the same way as the first example?

Comment: Unpacking `s` gives the exact result you want. What do you mean "I've previously tried unpacking the list, but ..."?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. By unpacking, I mean all the solutions I found online took the elements out of their individual lists and created one big list, i,e, s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1], which is not what I wanted to do. Wim's solution worked for me.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034014/how-to-apply-itertools-product-to-elements-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *argument unpacking*, demonstrated in the tutorial at [*4.8.5. Unpacking Argument Lists*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> print(list(product(*s)))
[(1, 4, -1), (1, 5, -1), (2, 4, -1), (2, 5, -1), (3, 4, -1), (3, 5, -1)]
```

Comment: Then they probably didn't try unpacking *correctly*.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi We don't know how they attempted to do so (not shown), or if they even know what that term actually means in context. This gets the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *

```
from itertools import product

s = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [-1]]
result = list(product(*s))
print(result)
```